# Shower Head Fluid Simulation: Domain too big issue

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to simulate and eventually animate a shower in blender. The simulation works fine when the domain is small but does not work at all when its large. And I need it to be large as I don't want splashing water when I animating it.
I am new Blender user (started yesterday) and tried playing around with various settings. All the scales are 1.0.

I currently have just on inflow but eventually plan to have a lot (75: one for each nozzle)

Here is my blender file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzhkRkqiPRPtRmh6N3F4TjVtaWc

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If splashing is not important why not use particles in fluid mode with a metaball render object.

[image: water render]

Use many thousands of particles with a short life (until they fall out of frame).

[image: particles]
[image: render object]

Add a metaball with very high resolution and set it to the render type.

[image: metaball]

Also I add Denoiser (B2.79) to clean up the surface of the water for animation. And I have added Children Particles in Simple mode. Just a multiple of 3.

[image: child particles]

Sadly I cannot get the motion blur to work on particles.

[image: water children]

Comment: Thanks a lot, will give it a try! But I would ideally want to use a continuous stream of water. Is is possible to increase the number of particles to make it look continuous?

Comment: The metaballs will stick together if there are smaller gaps between particles. So increase particle count or decrease speed of falling. Also water's surface tension controls stream self adherance, as it falls water tends to break up into balls.